# Spring data version annotation not incrementing when used on a mongo collection

Tags: java, versioning, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am using spring data with mongodb to store binary data such as images etc
I want to maintain a version field to append to the url to cheat the browser from caching images.

See my document base class below:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Version;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.Indexed;

public abstract class BaseDocument {

    @Id
    @Indexed(unique=true)
    protected long id;
    protected byte[] data;
    protected String mimeType;
    protected String filename;
    protected String extension;
    @Version
    private Long version;
```

I also have a repository wrapping MongoOperations for saving my documents.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class DocumentRepository implements IDocumentRepository {

    @Autowired
    private MongoOperations mongoTemplate;

    @Override
    public <D extends BaseDocument> void saveDocument(D document) {
        mongoTemplate.save(document);
    }
```

In an attempt to implement versioning, I did some hunting around and found that there was a @Version annotation for spring mongo but that is was deprecated. I then discovered that the spring data @Version annotation should used instead. So I went ahead and used the spring data @Version annotation.

What I expect to happen is that my version field would be incremented every time I save my document. I am overwriting the same document several times but my version field is not getting incremented as I am expecting.

Am I doing something incorrectly or is there something additional that I need to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to use @Version annotation you need to enable auditing in Spring Data MongoDB by adding one line to your application context:

```
<mongo:auditing />
```

Comment: Hi Maciej. I tried that but I was getting the following error from my ide "The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element mongo:auditing", I upgraded to 1.2.1 and referenced the 1.2.xsd where the auditing element is present. This has stopped the ide from giving the error but I am still recieivng this error at `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 70; columnNumber: 23; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mongo:auditing'` compile time. Any further suggesstions?

Comment: You need to have latest Spring Data MongoDB version - 1.2.1 on your classpath. If exception is still coming up check out my explanation how to use auditing: http://maciejwalkowiak.pl/blog/2013/05/24/auditing-entities-in-spring-data-mongodb/ . If you will still have problems paste your whole XML configuration here

Comment: Thanks for all of your help Maciej, I have managed to get it to work. After reading your blog I am playing around with the other audit fields as well.

Comment: Hi Trevor, I would appreciate if you share the concepts of versioning and auditing both at a time which is working fine in your case as you said. I am using @Version in model for auditing but while trying to update the corresponding document using Spring data MongoRepository save method, it's failing with "Duplicate Key Error" I have been digging more and more on this but nothing worked till now. Thanks!!