# Spring Data MongoDB: BigInteger to ObjectId conversion

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a problem with update query using Spring Data MongoDB. I retrieve some object's _id as BigInteger value. Then I want to make following query:

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(id));
Update update = new Update();
update.set("version",version);
mongoOperations.updateFirst(query, update, Audit.class);
```

Query part fails to match any documents since id value passed to `is()` somehow must be converted to ObjectId. I can't find any documentation on this kind of conversion. Will appreciate any help.

p.s.: SpringData Mongodb version 1.2

Comment: I also see that you are attempting to perform some kind of versioning. I would like to refer you tho [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665797/spring-data-version-annotation-not-incrementing-when-used-on-a-mongo-collection) that I asked re auditing with spring mongo, as it also to setup automatic versioning using annotations.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm happy enough with my versioning :-)

Answer (score 6):

You can convert it also manually:

```
ObjectId convertedId = new ObjectId(bigInteger.toString(16));
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(convertedId));
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to write a custom Spring converter BigInteger => ObjectId and ObjectId => BigInteger.

See the doc part here:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-document/docs/current/reference/html/#d0e2670

**------UPDATE------**

It seems that this kind of converter already exists in the Spring-Data-MongoDB library:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-document/docs/1.0.0.M1/api/org/springframework/data/document/mongodb/SimpleMongoConverter.ObjectIdToBigIntegerConverter.html

So you just have to specify it in your Spring configuration.

Comment: It's easier to say than to do :-). I've found this class in documentation to version 1.0 of Spring Data. But, I mentioned Spring data version for a reason - as far as I see there's no such converter in 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can add an 'id' field to your collection classes or potentially a base class and annotate it with org.springframework.data.annotation.Id, as below:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

public abstract class BaseDocument {

    @Id
    protected long id;
```

This will allow you to perform the queries of the form:

```
public boolean doesDocumentExist(Class clazz, long documentId) {
    Query queryCriteria = new Query(Criteria.where("id").is(documentId));
    return mongoTemplate.count(queryCriteria, clazz) == 1;
}
```

Annotating your own id field with '@Id' will store your id as the mongo objectId, therefore saving you from doing the conversion yourself.

Comment: You are getting something wrong. I do have an @Id on BigInteger field in my entity. And Spring Data really saves that BigInt as ObjectId. But... The problem is not in saving, but in passing value to Query.

Comment: @AleksandrKravets Alright, then all you need to do in your query is replace '_id' with whatever your field annotated id is named: i.e. if your id field is named "id" as in my example then just change your criteria as follows: Criteria.where("id").is(id)

Comment: Nope, didn't work. As I mentioned in question, the problem is not in field's name. It's in value type and lack of automatic conversion.

Comment: I find that surprising as the code I posted comes straight from my code base which works like a charm. There must something else going on. I am sorry that I was unable to be more help.

Comment: It should work. I've read some similar info on SO and other resources. As I understand Spring Data uses `id` as some kind of alias of `_id`. According to some sources in certain versions of SDM it works everywhere except update. Again, my problem isn't in field name.

Answer (score 0):

```
//get the converter from the mongoTemplate

MappingMongoConverter converter = (MappingMongoConverter)mongoTemplate.getConverter();

//get the conversion service from the mongo converter

ConversionService conversionService = converter.getConversionService();

//iterate the status list and get the each id to add the arraylist

for(Status status: statusList){

    ObjectId objectIdVal = conversionService.convert(status.getId(), ObjectId.class);

    **//here status.getId() returns the BigInteger**
    statusArrayList.add(objectIdVal);           
}

//get the users list whose status is active  and cancel

query.addCriteria(new Criteria().where("status.$id").in(statusArrayList));

List<User> usersList = mongoTemplate.find(query, User.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a `BigIngeter` to `ObjectId` using the hex representation of the `BigInteger`. However, an `ObjectId` is supposed to be exactly 24 characters long, and parsing a shorter string will fail in Java. Thus it's better to ensure that the hex representation is 0-padded appropriately:

```
String hexString24 = StringUtils.leftPad(bigInteger.toString(16), 24, "0");
ObjectId convertedId = new ObjectId(hexString24);
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(convertedId));
```